# Different way to index threads in CUDA C

Tags: matrix, indexing, cuda

I have 9x9 matrix and i flattened it into a vector of 81 elements; then i defined a grid of 9 blocks with 9 threads each for a total of 81 threads; here's a picture of the grid
[image]

Then i tried to verify what was the index related to the the thread (0,0) of block (1,1); first i calculated the i-th column and the j-th row like this:

i = blockDim.x*blockId.x + threadIdx.x = 3*1 + 0 = 3
j = blockDim.y*blockId.y + threadIdx.y = 3*1 + 0 = 3

therefore the index is:

index = N*i + j = 9*3 +3 = 30

As a matter of fact thread (0,0) of block (1,1) is actually the 30th element of the matrix;

Now here's my problem: let's say a choose a grid with 4 blocks (0,0)(1,0)(0,1)(1,1) with 4 threads each (0,0)(1,0)(0,1)(1,1)

Let's say i keep the original vector with 81 elements; what should i do to get the index of a generic element of the vector by using just 4*4 = 16 threads? i have tried the formulas written above but they don't seem to apply.
My goal is that every thread handles a single element of the vector...

Comment: In your first example, you had a 1:1 correspondence between threads (81 total) and elements (81 total).  You are now asking how to index 81 elements with 16 threads.  How do you want to assign elements per thread?  5 elements per thread, plus the first thread gets an extra element? If a thread will be responsible for 5 elements, how will you identify which element you are referring to?  The thread indexing no longer provides obvious answers.   This can't be answered until you define how you want elements to map to threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common way to have a smaller number of threads cover a larger number of data elements is to use a "grid-striding loop".  Suppose I had a vector of length `n` elements, and I had some smaller number of threads, and I wanted to take every element, add 1 to it, and store it back in the original vector.  That code could look something like this:

```
__global__ void my_inc_kernel(int *data, int n){
  int idx = (gridDim.x*blockDim.x)*(threadIdx.y+blockDim.y*blockIdx.y) + (threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x);
  while(idx < n){
    data[idx]++;
    idx += (gridDim.x*blockDim.x)*(gridDim.y*blockDim.y);}
  }
```

(the above is coded in browser, not tested)

The only complicated parts above are the indexing parts.  The initial calculation of `idx` is just a typical creation/assignment of a globally unique id (`idx`) to each thread in a 2D threadblock/grid structure.  Let's break it down:

```
  int idx = (gridDim.x*blockDim.x)*(threadIdx.y+blockDim.y*blockIdx.y) +
        (width of grid in threads)*(thread y-index)

                                                 (threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x);
                                                   (thread x-index)
```

The amount added to `idx` on each pass of the while loop is the size of the 2D grid in total threads.  Therefore, each iteration of the while loop does one "grid's width" of elements at a time, and then "strides" to the next grid-width, to process the next group of elements.  Let's break that down:

```
    idx += (gridDim.x*blockDim.x)*(gridDim.y*blockDim.y);
       (width of grid in threads)*(height of grid in threads)
```

This methodology does not require that the total number of elements be evenly divisible the number of threads.  The conditional check of the while-loop handles all cases of relationship between vector size and grid size.

This particular grid-striding loop methodology has the additional benefit (in terms of mapping elements to threads) that it tends to naturally promote coalesced access.  The reads and writes to `data` vector in the code above will coalesce perfectly, due to the behavior of the grid-striding loop.  You can enhance coalescing behavior in this case by choosing blocks that are a whole-number multiple of 32, but that is not central to your question.

Comment: Ok it's all very clear and it answers my question (thanks!!).. there's only one doubt still: when you define the index you multiply times 'width of grid in threads'... why not the height?

Comment: To compute a linear index from row and column of a matrix, I take the row I am in (the y-index) and multiply it by the width of the row (width of grid in threads).  Then I add the column (the x-index).  This computation does not involve the height of the matrix.